# Python Argument TypeError

Tags: python-3.x

Can somebody tell me why I am getting error in it?

```
import math
class Weight():
    def area(r):
        return math.pi*r*r
obj=Weight()
r=int(input("Enter the radius of circle"))
print(obj.area(r))
```

```
TypeError: area() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Add self as first argument to area method

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `self`:

```py
import math
class Weight():
    def area(self, r):
        return math.pi*r*r
obj=Weight()
r=int(input("Enter the radius of circle"))
print(obj.area(r))
```

---

If you're writing a class, that is not actually needs to be instantiated, or writing a method, that does not actually need an instance, you can use `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` decorators. The first one replaces an instance (`self == Weight()`) with the class itself (`cls == Weight`); the second one doesn't pass the first argument at all.

Below is the example of their use:

```py
import math
class Weight:
    @staticmethod
    def area(r):
        return math.pi*r*r

    @classmethod
    def double_area(cls, r):
        return cls.area(r) * 2


r=int(input("Enter the radius of circle"))
print(Weight.area(r))
print(Weight.double_area(r))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add self as first argument to area method as such:

```
import math
class Weight():
    def area(self, r):
        return math.pi*r*r
obj=Weight()
r=int(input("Enter the radius of circle"))
print(obj.area(r))
```